# How to solve Apollo subscriptions "Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400"

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-link

I have a legacy application working with React and subscribing to a GraphQL backend. Today, I upgraded all my packages especially thoses (I suppopse that they are the origin of my problem but I'm not sure):

- `react-apollo` from **^2.4.0** to **^3.1.3**
- `apollo-link-ws` from **^1.0.14** to **^1.0.19**

The working code was this:

```
import {ApolloClient} from 'apollo-client';
import {HttpLink} from 'apollo-link-http';
import {WebSocketLink} from 'apollo-link-ws';
// Other imports....

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: `ws://localhost:3000/graphql`,
  options: {
    reconnect: true,
  },
});

const splittedLink = split(
  ({query}) => {
    const {kind, operation} = getMainDefinition(query);
    return (
      kind === 'OperationDefinition' && operation === 'subscription'
    );
  },
  wsLink,
  httpLink,
);

const link = ApolloLink.from([
  onError(({graphQLErrors, networkError}) => {
    // Handle graphQLErrors and networkError
  }),
  withClientState({
    //...
    cache
  }),
  splittedLink
]);

export default new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache
});
```

So it's the basic code as described on [Apollo website](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/) but after the upgrade I'm getting this error (when looking on my graphQL response in the network):

> Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

and in my dev terminal, I see an infinite logs saying:

[image]

**Remark**

In my `setupProxy.js` I have `ws` set to true:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = app => {
  app.use(proxy('/graphql', {
    target: 'ws://my-backend-url:my-backend-port',
    changeOrigin: true,
    ws: true,
  }));
};
```

Any feedback or experience about this?

Comment: Were you able to fix it? Killing me for few days now. :(

Comment: Always waiting for an a solution or an idea.